# Change Bootloader title to include bit

Tags: grub2, 64-bit, bootloader, 32-bit, architecture

Secondlife runs on 32 bit linux. I've tried WINE, Crossover, and installing the 32 bit libraries. Nothing has worked so now I'm having to install a 32 bit copy of Ubuntu as a second partition just to play a GAME that has linux support already. Anywho, how do I set the bootloader up to tell me whether I'm running Ubuntu 32 or 64 at boot?

Comment: Install grub customizer. That will let you edit the entry for each OS so you can type in the bit for each.